# PowerShell .NET Preloading a form

Tags: .net, winforms, forms, powershell

I have two forms where one is the main form (`Show-MainForm`) with lots of buttons and stuff on it which loads fast. Then there is another form (`Show-SelectionBox`) which takes 25 seconds or more to load because it needs to query some stuff.

The selection box form is called when pressing a button in the main form. So I was looking for a way to already start loading the selection box form but don't show it yet, so it will be quicker available when people would click the button that invokes it.

Is there a way to preload this selection box form? Thank you for your help.

**Example code:**

```
Function Show-SelectionBox {
    Function Add-Node($Nodes, $Path) {  
        $Path.Split("/") | % {
            Write-Verbose "Searching For: $_"
            $SearchResult = $Nodes.Find($_, $False)

        If ($SearchResult.Count -eq 1) {
          Write-Verbose "Selecting: $($SearchResult.Name)"
          $Nodes = $SearchResult[0].Nodes
        }
        Else {
          Write-Verbose "Adding: $_"
          $Node = New-Object Windows.Forms.TreeNode($_)
          $Node.Name = $_
          $Nodes.Add($Node)  | Out-Null
        }
      }
    }

    Function Get-CheckedNodes {
        Param (
            $nodes
        )
        foreach ($n in $Nodes) {
            if ($n.nodes.count -gt 0) {
                Get-CheckedNodes $n.nodes
            }
            if ($n.checked) {
                Write-Output $n.Name
            }           
        }   
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 #slow loading

    $script:SelectedOU = $null

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.ClientSize = '342, 502'
    $Form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'

    $ButtonOK_Click = {
        $script:SelectedOU = Get-CheckedNodes $treeView.Nodes
        $Form.close()
    }

    $TreeView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
    $TreeView.Dock = 'Fill'
    $TreeView.CheckBoxes = $true

    Add-Node $TreeView.Nodes "Fruits"  
    Add-Node $TreeView.Nodes "Vegetables"  
    Add-Node $TreeView.Nodes "Cars" 

    $ButtonCancel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $ButtonCancel.text = “&Cancel”
    $ButtonCancel.Location = '120,467'
    $ButtonCancel.size = '75,23'
    $ButtonCancel.Anchor = 'Bottom, Left'
    $ButtonCancel.add_Click({$Form.close()})
    $Form.Controls.Add($ButtonCancel)

    $ButtonOK = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $ButtonOK.Location = '245,467'
    $ButtonOK.Size = '75,23'
    $ButtonOK.Name = 'ButtonOK'
    $ButtonOK.Text = 'OK'
    $ButtonOK.add_Click($ButtonOK_Click)
    $Form.Controls.Add($ButtonOK)
    $Form.Controls.Add($TreeView)

    $Form.ShowDialog() > $null
}

Function Show-MainForm {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
    $Form.ClientSize = '665,474'
    $Form.MaximizeBox = $False
    $Form.AutoSize = $False
    $Form.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
    $Form.Text = 'Script Center'

    $Text = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Text.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",14,1,3,1)
    $Text.Location = '1,20'
    $Text.Size = '380,40'
    $Text.Text = 'Welcome to Script Center'
    $Text.BackColor = 'Transparent'
    $Text.TextAlign = 'TopCenter'
    $Form.Controls.Add($Text)

    $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Button.Text = 'Launch Selectionbox'
    $Button.TabIndex = 2
    $Button.add_Click({Show-SelectionBox})
    $Button.Location = '8,60'
    $Button.Size = '100,35'
    $Form.Controls.Add($Button)

    $Panel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    $Panel.Location = '122,60'
    $Panel.Size = '535,390'
    $Panel.TabIndex = 8
    $Panel.BackColor = 'CornflowerBlue'
    $Panel.BorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
    $Form.Controls.Add($Panel)

    $Form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
}

Show-MainForm
```

Comment: You'll have to significantly re-architect your application to work round this, and you'll still have to wait 25 seconds if the app is opened and the button is immediately clicked, so you're really only _hiding_ the fundamental problem. You're also really reaching the limits of PowerShell here. This would be much better suited to winforms or WPF using C#/VB.NET. You're getting very much into the world of threads and delegates, really beyond the scope/design of PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback arco444, I think you're right. I'm now looking into Visual Studio 2013, C# WPF Applications. It would be nice if there was a freeware IDE for this.

Comment: You should be able to get Visual Studio Express from Microsoft which is free. Doesn't have all the features of the paid versions but more then enough to get you started. Check [this link](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx)